# How to Remove Left Side Scroll Bar in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

There's a left side vertical scroll bar showing up on my website only in IE desktop browser. I'm trying to figure out how to remove the left side scroll bar in IE. In other browsers (including tablet browsers) its not showing which is good.

This issue is showing up in IE Edge and older versions of IE as well.

The left side vertical scroll bar is showing up underneath the fixed position header nav and it doesn't seem to have a function because the right side bar still does the scrolling. I believe it has something to do with this header nav because after adding the header nav that's when this bug popped up.

Hopefully this is enough information to solve the issue.

overflow-y: hidden; isn't working or overflow: hidden; or overflow: auto; and other fixes I've seen aren't working either.

Here's an image of the issue:

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean by ltr?

Comment: I meant RTL Right to Left - Arab or Israeli for example

Comment: Nope, it's left to right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in the css declaration `-ms-overflow-style: none;`

Comment: Didn't quite work, I put it in: body { -ms-overflow-style: none; } and then it removed bother left and right scroll bars, so it eliminated one too many.

Comment: body{overflow-y:hidden;} removes the right scroll bar, but not the left scroll bar if that helps.